# Android studio location of caches/generated sources

Tags: android-studio

I have switched to using Android Studio 3.1 RC2. I have detected that when I switch branches, I am running across generated sources from other branch. They still show up even if I do Build -> Clean Project. Or manually delete `build` folders in all my modules as well as top level build folder.

Only way to rectify this is delete .gradle folder in my project directory and my $HOME/.gradle , this is very time consuming.

Where does Android Studio keep its caches of `generated` files. I have tried Android Studio's clean "Invalidate Caches/Restart" without much help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
to clean up all caches under HOME/.gradle

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html